# add columns to a a numpy matrix based on degree of polynomial

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix

firstly, apologize for little cryptic title to my question. Let me try to explain my need:-
I am reading two features namely X1, X2 from a CSV file. I have a training set of data in a csv file containing 1000 records with each line corresponding to the value of X1, X2. To make my training set fit better to my machine learning code, I want to do feature mapping that would take X1, X2 and create polynomial terms to the power of 4.  for example if X1 =a, X2=b, I want to add newer features a^2, a*b, b^2, a^3,a^2*b,a*b^2,a^4...and so on. 
Now if I read them as a numpy matrix , I want to see the data like this:

```
[ [ 1 a b a^2 a*b, b^2 a^3  a^2*b......]
  [....  ............   ............   ]
  [ ..
                                   ..] ]
```

Note that the number of rows are fixed , but the number of columns are determined by the degree selected. Also first three columns need to be

```
  [[1 a b ..]
  [1 c d ..]
  ..
  ..]
```

The pseudo code I am thinking of is as follows:-

```
 def poly(X): # where X is a numpy matrix with X1, X2 columns,
   degree = 4;
   r= X.shape[0]
   c=1 # number of columns

   val_matrix= np.ones(shape=(r,c)) # creating a (r,1) matrix init with 1s
   # *start of psuedo code*
   while i<=degree:
      while j <=i:
         val_matrix[:, c+1] = (X1.^(i-j)).*(X2.^j)
```

I am not sure how to get this working in python?. would appreciate some suggestion. Note that ^ refers to the power of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with two vectors `X1` and `X2` you could create the monomials:

```
X1p = X1[:, None]**np.arange(max_deg + 1)
X2p = X2[:, None]**np.arange(max_deg + 1)
```

and then combine them using `mgrid`

```
i, j = np.mgrid[:max_deg + 1,:max_deg + 1]
m = i+j <= max_deg
result = X1p[:, i[m]]*X2p[:, j[m]]
```

Alternatively you could apply the indices directly to `X1` and `X2`:

```
result = X1[:, None]**i[m] * X2[:, None]**j[m]
```

This requires fewer lines of code but uses more multiplications.

If the number of multiplications is a concern, `X1p` and `X2p` could also be computed cheaper; `X1p`:

```
X1p = np.empty((len(X1), max_deg + 1), X1.dtype)
X1p[:, 0] = 1
X1p[:, 1:] = X1[:, None]
np.multiply.accumulate(X1p[:,1:], axis=-1, out=X1p[:, 1:])
```

and similar for `X2p`

Comment: thanks Paul. this exposes my weakness in numpy. let me try this out and get back to you. appreciate it.

Comment: thank you , it worked. you also exposed me to np.mgrid.that is helpful.